# Changing the SpeechSynthesis voice not working

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have tried all the variations I can find on stackoverflow, but I can still not get the voice to change on SpeechSynthesis

Below is the standalone code that fills a dropdown with all the available voices and allows me to select which voice I want.

Unfortunately this code does not change the voice. Also, before changing the voice. msg.voice is null, even though it has been used to list all the available voices.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? (console.log(msg.voice); gives a null before being set)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT>
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
var numberOfVoices=0;


function Main(){
voiceSelect=document.getElementById("voiceSelect");
setTimeout(getVoicesFunction,2000);
}

function getVoicesFunction(){
msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello");
numberOfVoices=0;   
speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice) {
var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = voice.voiceURI;
        voiceSelect.add(option, 0);
        numberOfVoices=numberOfVoices+1;
});
    voiceSelect.onchange = voiceChange;
}

function voiceChange(){
    textToSpeech("this is the old voice");
    var selectedOption = this[this.selectedIndex];
    selectedVoice = selectedOption.text;
    msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    console.log("before change msg.voice");
    console.log(msg.voice);
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfVoices ; i++) {
    if(voices[i].voiceURI === selectedVoice) {
    var temp="changing the voice number to "+i;
    setTimeout(textToSpeech,2000,temp);
    msg.voice = voices[i];
    console.log(msg.voice);
    var tempVoiceNumber=i;
    };
    }
    setTimeout(textToSpeech,4000,"this is the new voice");
}

function textToSpeech(tspeech){
    msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.text = tspeech;
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    console.log("speech "+tspeech);
}       
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body onload= "Main()" id= "mainb">
<div id="container">
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="voiceSelect">
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so many setTimeouts? Try the first example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis#Examples

Comment: Thanks Frazer - I use timeouts because the standard methods as per your link do not work without them. I assume it is the async nature of javascript - you will see that on many of the questions on speech synthesis - part of the solution has been to put in time delays.  I find it amazing that the mozilla documentation - or any other official documentaion does not mention this. For example voices.lengthis zero without a time delay.  Not all of the ones in there are necessary, but I have put them all in to be on the safe side and to show that even with time delays the chages still do not work

Comment: In the linked example there's a section with onvoiceschanged. This is how to get the voices without using timeouts. The answers with timeouts are not worth reading.

Comment: Thanks, but that was the very piece of code that I started with. On three separate machines and operating systems, it gives voices.length as zero, unless you put in a time delay. Then it at least gives the correct length of voices, and also the correct list of voices. Unfortunaltely, it still does not actually change the voice. I realise that I may be doing something wrong, which is why I listed the whole html with the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IanR, I copied the code and it works for me. I cut out the pitch and rate controls and made the html simpler, but it's basically the same.

If it doesn't work for you are you getting any console errors?

```js
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

var inputForm = document.querySelector('form');
var inputTxt = document.querySelector('.txt');
var voiceSelect = document.querySelector('select');

/*var pitch = document.querySelector('#pitch');
var pitchValue = document.querySelector('.pitch-value');
var rate = document.querySelector('#rate');
var rateValue = document.querySelector('.rate-value');*/



var voices = [];

function populateVoiceList() {
  voices = synth.getVoices();

  for (i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = voices[i].name + ' (' + voices[i].lang + ')';

    if (voices[i].default) {
      option.textContent += ' -- DEFAULT';
    }

    option.setAttribute('data-lang', voices[i].lang);
    option.setAttribute('data-name', voices[i].name);
    voiceSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
}

populateVoiceList();
if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;
}

inputForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(inputTxt.value);
  var selectedOption = voiceSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-name');
  for (i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    if (voices[i].name === selectedOption) {
      utterThis.voice = voices[i];
    }
  }
  //utterThis.pitch = pitch.value;
  //utterThis.rate = rate.value;
  synth.speak(utterThis);

  inputTxt.blur();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>61016951</title>
  <script src="61016951.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="txt">
      <select></select>
      <button type="submit">Play</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Frazer - many apologies - I did post a comment thanking you for this, but I obviously pressed the wrong button because it is not visible. Yes you are right, this code does work on windows. Thank you for taking the time to show that. I appreciate it. It does remove the need for time outs. The reason my code did not work was because I was using a function that invoked new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(). I did not reset the voices to the relevant voices[voiceNumber].  My problem is now, getting it working on IoS. But I am looking at this now and will update this thread when solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @IanR I'm sure I saw your comment yesterday, I even upvoted it!

Comment: Both iOS and Android lie about the voices that are available when you call getVoices().  iOS gives you one per locale that you can actually use, Android gives you one per language.  You can change which one Android gives you from the device settings (and restarting). With iOS you can maintain a list of the voices that actually work and ignore the rest.  More info here: https://talkrapp.com/speechSynthesis.html

Answer (score 1):

Stripping out all the extra bits in your code, here's how you'll need to handle the asynchronous loading on `speechSynthesis.getVoices()`;

```js
if (voiceLoaded()) {
  speak();
} else {
  speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', speak);
}

function speak() {
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('text');
  utterance.voice = getFemaleVoice();
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}

function getFemaleVoice() {
  const voiceIndex = 4;
  return speechSynthesis.getVoices()[voiceIndex];
}

function voiceLoaded() {
  return speechSynthesis.getVoices().length;
}
```

If the voices array has loaded already then it'll speak the utterance, otherwise this code will add the event listener on the `voiceschanged` event which will fire once the browser loads the array of voices and then your callback to speak will run.